# SQL Join query from two table

Tags: sql, wordpress, join

I am trying to do SQL query with JOIN. But without success.

I am trying to sort this query

```
SELECT ID, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE `post_type`='wc_booking'
```

With this (_booking_start ascending).

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_booking_start'
```

Question how would JOIN query look in this case?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you simply need to do this:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_parent, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_booking_start'
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'wc_booking'
```

Comment: Super!! It works